# How to delete the columns except the first three columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where after all the operations are done I want to clear all the contents except in first three columns (A, B, C).

Is it possible to achieve using VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove formula and values use:

```
Range("D:XFD").ClearContents
```

To remove formula, values and formatting, use:

```
Range("D:XFD").Clear
```

Comment: Its working fine, is it possible to clear all the contents except for first 3 columns and the entire first row?

I cleared all whole excel sheet except for the first row suing the below code

    Rows(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1).ClearContents

How can it be merged with your code so that i can accomplish both the task at the one shot

Comment: `Range("D2:XFD1048576")`
I would suggest you look up the documentation on `Range` object at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx. StackOverflow is not really a code writing service, although we try our best to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @municontractor Its working just as i expected. Have a good day ahead!